# Magento product collection and group by categories

Tags: magento

How can I create a Magento collection of products with adding in the end of my collection a "GROUP BY" categories ??

Thanks for help.

**[edit]:**

I have tried this :

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
->addAttributeToSelect('*')

$productCollection->getSelect()->group(array('name'));
```

but it don't works, I have tested the generated query and it say in phpmyadmin : `#1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'group statement`

Comment: and what is the point of grouping multiple rows of product information to one row by category?

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean with your question, but I'm trying to do that to change the structure and the organisation of my products in my Magento shop. I have some simple products with the same name, and now I want to group them to create grouped and associated products... Thanks for help.

Comment: I have tried this :
`$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
$productCollection->getSelect()->group(array('name'));`
but it don't works, I have tested the generated  query and it say in phpmyadmin : `#1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'group statement`

Comment: echo out the generated query and see what fields are included

Answer (score -1, accepted):

start from here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

continue here

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html

profit $$$$

Comment: @Bizboss i am facing the same problem. Can you please help me how did you manage to solve the problem after reading the above articles.

Comment: Both links are broken